# Pigeonhole principle problem. Given 12 different pairs of numbers, show that at least two of them have a difference of the form $aa$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given 12 different two-digit numbers, show that at least two of them have a difference of the form $aa$.

I am not even sure I understand the question, but it says the pigeonhole principle should be used. What is being asked here?

Original question (Swedish):
Givet 12 olika tvåsiffriga tal. Visa att minst två av dem har en skillnad av
form aa.

Comment: This sounds like you may have copied it wrong. Do you perhaps mean "Given $12$ different numbers"? And is there no information on the range of the numbers? How did this problem arise?

Comment: "$aa$"  can't be a two digit number like $11, 22, \dots$ because the pairs might all inbolve very big numbers.  Have you stated all the hypotheses? Perhaps all the numbers in all the pairs are less than some prescribed bound.

Comment: Nope, it says "Give 12 different two numbered numbers...". The question is not in English, but that is how the questions is.

Comment: I have copied the question as it is. There is unfortunately nothing more :s

Comment: OK "two numbered numbers" means the numbers have two digits each. That's not the same as "pairs of numbers". Please edit the question to make that clear.

Comment: @DoubleOseven Add the fact in the main question that the numbers all have $2$ digits.

Comment: Can you reprint the question in its original language?  Some one here might be able to interpret that better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that there are $11$ residue classes $\pmod {11}$.  Thus, amongst your $12$ there must be $m\equiv n\pmod {11}$.  But if $m>n$ then $m-n$ is a two digit number divisible by $11$, hence of the form $aa$.

Comment: Why did you choose $mod 11$?

Comment: Because the feature that characterizes $\{11,22,\dots,99\}$ is divisibility by $11$.

Comment: Ok, I think I have misunderstood the question. Isn't for example 25 a viable two digit number?

Comment: Of course it is.  So what?  Your problem says..pick any list of twelve two digit numbers, let's say $\{20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,78\}$.  Following my remark, we note that $78\equiv 23 \pmod {11}$ and, indeed, $78-23=55$, just as you want.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks :)